# How can i transmit the sender as an eventarg

Tags: c#, events

Instance X of a class register to the change event of instances Y of the same class.

I want to update X if Y is changed, but i dont want to use the static keyword all over the class. Is there a way to transmit the recipient of the event in the eventargs?

Here is some example code with an NUnit tests to illustrate where my problem lies exactly. I compiled and ran it. Two tests just verify the programming. The failing test illustrates my problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Eventtest
{
    public class DependencyChain
    {
        public static int demonstrationcount = 0;

        private String hiddenstring = "";
        public String visiblestring
        {
            get { return hiddenstring; }
            set
            {
                hiddenstring = value;
                NotifyOnStringChanged();
            }
        }

        private void NotifyOnStringChanged()
        {
            if (changed != null)
            {
                changed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        } 

        public EventHandler changed;

        private EventHandler Observer = new EventHandler((o, e) => {
            DependencyChain sender = (o as DependencyChain);
            demonstrationcount++;
            //THE FOLLOWING DOES NOT WORK SINCE "this" IS NOT STATIC
            //DependencyChain recipient = this;
            //recipient.visiblestring = sender.visiblestring;
        });

        public DependencyChain(string initialstring)
        {
            this.visiblestring = initialstring;
        }

        public DependencyChain(DependencyChain other)
        {
            this.visiblestring = other.visiblestring;
            other.changed += Observer;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return visiblestring;
        }

    }

    [TestFixture]
    class Eventtest
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void ResetStaticCounter()
        {
            DependencyChain.demonstrationcount = 0;
        }

        [Test]//PASS
        public void ShouldInitialiseAndCopyValues()
        {
            DependencyChain Y = new DependencyChain("initial");
            DependencyChain X = new DependencyChain(Y);
            Assert.AreEqual(X.ToString(), Y.ToString());
        }

        [Test]//PASS
        public void ShouldCallObserverOnChange()
        {
            DependencyChain Y = new DependencyChain("initial");
            DependencyChain X = new DependencyChain(Y);
            Assert.AreEqual(0, DependencyChain.demonstrationcount);
            Y.visiblestring = "changed";
            Assert.AreEqual(1, DependencyChain.demonstrationcount);
        }

        [Test]//FAIL
        public void ShouldChangeStringOnChange()
        {
            DependencyChain Y = new DependencyChain("initial");
            DependencyChain X = new DependencyChain(Y);
            Y.visiblestring = "changed";
            Assert.AreEqual(X.ToString(), Y.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only have to move the initialization of `Observer` to a constructor of `DependencyChain`, so you can capture `this`.

Comment: That worked. Uncommented the code, moved to a method, called method in constructor. Thanks

Comment: OK, good. You could also write the evt handler as a 'normal' method instead of a lambda.